# how to create sub-domains

Tags: asp.net, subdomain

i am going to create some sub-domains on my website.
when i create a sub-domain i must define a directory that sub-domain will refer to newly created sub-domain. but i want a different solution.

i want to detect when a user enters a URL , which sub-domain is used and then do some operation for each special sub-domain.
for example if website user entered a.mysite.com
i extract "a" sub-domain from URL and then without redirecting webpage i load some data in page.

please help me how i do these,on both web-server and localhost?

Comment: Which language are you working in?

Answer (score 1):

In general your application doesn't care about the host name, so you have to configure your IIS to handle all requests.

- **Production only:** Create a wildcard DNS record for your domain (e.g. ***.domain.tld**)
- Your IIS site should have no explicit bindings, so that ALL incoming requests hit this application (other sites should still work fine!).

After this you can check the `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` and extract the requested subdomain.